# Can I use a USA GFCI Intex Pool pump in New Zealand

Tags: gfci, 120-240v

I have imported an Intex salt system for use on a locally purchased intex pool. when I received it , the plug is a GFCI plug with a test and reset button on it.  the pump is a 230w pump. I purchased a 1000w step down transformer that appears to have a 3 wire configuration.

Still no power. Do I need a specific GFCI outlet or something?  Excuse my ignorance.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: The plug in intex pumps I have worked on are 120 v. They have the GFCI device within 12/18 inches of the end of the cord. If the supply voltage is not correctly polarized neutral/hot the GFCI will not reset. I have fixed 2 of these in the past for this reason. If 240 hot neutral it may be similar but not sure.

Comment: What kind of plug is it?  Which of these sockets would it plug into? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHS8W.png

Answer (score 2):

For future readers:

NO: US motors are 60Hz, while NZ are 50Hz (your new pump will run 27% slower). Even if you transform the voltage, that will not ensure that other electronics work as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or cut off the US GFCI and replace with the proper plug for your area.  Hire an electrician to do it for you if you have to.